# Sum of multiple lines inside nested arrays with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I got a booking, which have several invoices, each invoice have several invoiceLines.

I want my aggregate to select bookings joined with invoices, and then just give me the total for all invoiceLines.amountTotal.

Example booking table:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "0PDLR", 
    "checkin" : 1488326400, 
    "checkout" : 1498780800, 
}
```

Example invoice table:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "bookingId" : "0PDLR", 
    "invoiceLines" : [
        {
            "lineText" : "Rent Price", 
            "amountTotal" : 3000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount", 
            "amountTotal" : -500
        }, 
    ] 
}   
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "bookingId" : "0PDLR", 
    "invoiceLines" : [
        {
            "lineText" : "Final cleaning", 
            "amountTotal" : 200
        }, 
    ] 
}   
{ 
    "_id" : 3, 
    "bookingId" : "0PDLR", 
    "invoiceLines" : [
        {
            "lineText" : "Taxi to Airport", 
            "amountTotal" : 300
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Reservation fee paid already", 
            "amountTotal" : -500
        }
    ] 
}
```

This is the result I would like to get:

```
booking Result: [
    {
        "_id": "0PDLR",
        "checkin": 1488326400,
        "checkout": 1498780800,
        "sum": 2500
    }
]
```

This is my current aggregate pipeline:

```
    bookingTable.aggregate([
        { "$match": myMatch },
        {                                                                 
            $lookup: {                                                    
                from: "invoice",                                          
                localField: "_id",                                        
                foreignField: "bookingId",                                
                as: "invoice"                                             
            }                                                             
        },                                                                
        {                                                                  
            $project:{                                                     
                "_id" : 1,                                                
                "checkin" : 1,                                            
                "checkout" : 1,                                           
                "invoiceLines" : "$invoice.invoiceLines"                  
            }                                                              
        }                                                                  
    ])
```

Which of cause just returns a booking with all the invoice lines one by one,
so I will have to to the usual:

```
    var invoiceTotal = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<selectBooking[b].invoiceLines.length; i++) {
        for (var x=0; x<selectBooking[b].invoiceLines.length; x++) {    
            for (var y=0; y<selectBooking[b].invoiceLines[x].length; y++) { 
                invoiceTotal += selectBooking[b].invoiceLines[x][y].amountTotal
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is, can I do this in MongoDB instead?

Is there a way to make it count all the invoiceLines.amountTotal and then just return a sum in the $project ?

Comment: Sums up the defined value from all documents in the collection: Example : `db.COLLECTION_NAME.aggregate(AGGREGATE_OPERATION)`

Comment: So the sum of all invoice lines for each booking?

Comment: @NeilLunn that is correct.  Is that possible to do?

Comment: @SNTiwari im not sure I understand what you want to do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires MongoDB 3.2 at least, but you can do this using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
 bookingTable.aggregate([
   { "$match": myMatch },
   { "$lookup": {
     "from": "invoice",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "bookingId",
     "as": "invoice"
   }},
   { "$project": {
     "checkin" : 1,
     "checkout" : 1,
     "bookingTotal": {
       "$sum": {
         "$map": {
           "input": "$invoice",
           "as": "iv",
           "in": {
             "$sum": {
               "$map": {
                 "input": "$$iv.invoiceLines",
                 "as": "il",
                 "in": "$$il.amountTotal"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }}
])
```

Which is really just iterating through each array and reducing the result down to a single value for each line from the `"amountTotal"`.

With 3.4 you can make that a little less terse with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/):

```
 bookingTable.aggregate([
   { "$match": myMatch },
   { "$lookup": {
     "from": "invoice",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "bookingId",
     "as": "invoice"
   }},
   { "$project": {
     "checkin" : 1,
     "checkout" : 1,
     "bookingTotal": {
       "$reduce": {
         "input": "$invoice",
         "initialValue": 0,
         "in": {
           "$sum": [
             { "$reduce": {
               "input": "$$this.invoiceLines",
               "initialValue": 0,
               "in": { "$sum": [ "$$this.amountTotal", "$$value" ] }
             }},
             "$$value"
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }}
])
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand it, but im gonna try it for sure :)

Comment: YES!!! It worked like a charm!! Thank you so much for showing me how to do this.  Just to try and understand, you first map the invoice records, and inside those you map the lines from the invoice.  I would never have thought of this :)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard No problem. If you can use a latest MongoDB 3.4 the `$reduce` operator makes it a "little" less terse and possibly a bit clearer.

Comment: Ya, $reduce is pretty powerful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` in 3.4 version.

Think of `amountTotal` as `[[3000, -500], [200], [300, -500]]`. Inner `$reduce` to transform `amountTotal` to `[3000, -500, 200, 300, -500]` followed by outer `$reduce` to sum the amounts.

```
 { "$addFields": {
     "invoiceTotal": 
             {
           $reduce: {
              input: {
               $reduce: {
                  input: "$invoice.invoiceLines",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: { $concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this.amountTotal"] }
               }
             },
              initialValue: 0,
              in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this"] } 
           }
        }
   }}
```

Comment: Hi again @Veeram - as usual you come up with good solutions!!  I was thinking of using $concat at first, but had no idea how to make it work.  Thanks for explaining $reduce, I can use that one in many of my other aggregates, What does the double $$ signs mean? Im not sure about that one.

Comment: Its notation to access aggregation variables. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce